# AMD Radeon 6970 drivers cause black screen

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I have a AMD Radgeon 6970 graphics card and my computer will frequently black screen, i.e. Nothing is getting sent to my monitor and everything is frozen. Similar to this question and issue: [AMD Radeon GPU driver installation cause black screen](https://superuser.com/questions/940893/amd-radeon-gpu-driver-installation-cause-black-screen) 
This issue does not occur in safe mode. and the computer seems to work fine. There are no hardware events that I see coming out of the gpu, monitor, or processor. The only events I can see are adminstrative events for DCOM 1084 for ShellHWDetection and BITS detection. Is there anywhere I am missing to look for errors for this black screen issue?

Relevant computer info is:
OS - Windows 10 64 Bit - This is a fresh install created recently download from Microsoft media creation tool.
MoBo - https://www.asus.com/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/MAXIMUS_IV_GENEZ/
Processor - i5-2500k
Graphics card - AMD Radeon 6970 - Driver version: 15.200.1055.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further testing, it turns out the card itself was dying. I switched over to Windows 7 and last driver that I knew that worked. However the problem was still occurring and it would only work in safe Mode. The fix ended up being buying a new graphics card.